# Can't move stencil

Tags: texture-painting, masking

I currently have a problem with Blender: With texture painting, if I set a stencil I can't move it with the right mouse button, does anyone have any idea why this could be?

---

[image]It looks like this. So I don't think, this is the error

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the RIGHT MOUSE shortcut is correctly assigned to move the stencil.

The path is `Edit (menu) > Preferences > Keymap > Name > "stencil" (type) > Image Paint > Stencil Brush Control (tool: Translation)`. See the image below for a better understanding.

[image]